# How to convert datetime type column in int so it can be used with '> < =' operators

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need this SQL to be able to have additional condition:

```
select sum(cost) as totalCost from monthly_costs_tracker 
                       where date_of_month <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I want to be able to add an 'and' operator after CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for example:

```
select sum(cost) as totalCost from monthly_costs_tracker
where date_of_month <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and date_of_month >= '2017-11-01%'
```

EDITED: So I need this query to track the entered values in a column 'costs'.
It calculates the sum of all entered records. I want to upgrade it by setting a time period on which to calculate. 
For example when December, comes I need the calculation of the sum to take place only in records with date > 2017-12

[image]

Comment: You can use those relational operators fine with datetime columns. Show some example data so we can see what problem you are having. The percent character is certainly incorrect.

Comment: This is the initial query I needed:
select sum(cost) totalCost from monthly_costs_tracker
       where date_of_month <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and date_of_month > '2017-11%'

It throws this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Edit your question and show example data and desired results so we don’t have to guess.

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: provide example data in tabular form.

Comment: Done, see the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159292/discussion-between-sosomqk-and-martin-smith).

Answer (score 2):

To get month-to-date:

```
select sum(cost) as totalCost
from monthly_costs_tracker
where date_of_month <= getdate() and
      date_of_month >= dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date)
```

Or, you can use `datefromparts()`:

```
select sum(cost) as totalCost
from monthly_costs_tracker
where date_of_month <= getdate() and
      date_of_month >= datefromparts(year(getdate), month(getdate), 1);
```

Feel free to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  I'm just in the (perhaps bad) habit of using `getdate()` in SQL Server.

You should never use `like` on dates.  If you feel the need, explicitly convert to a string before hand (although that is almost never necessary).

Answer (score 0):

According to your query I think you want:

```
select sum(cost) totalCost 
from monthly_costs_tracker 
where (date_of_month <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
and (REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, date_of_month, 102), '.', '-')  > '2017-11%');
```

You can see **[CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)** to see the styles.

Comment: Yeah, that's great mate, thank you!!
If you don't mind will you explain me what this number 102 represents (or send me a link to an article)?

Comment: @Sosomqk Sure hold on

Comment: ugh. converting it to string makes it unsargable and is completely unnecessary. and why the percent in `> '2017-11%'`? the percent character doesnt have any special significance in string comparisons other than like and patindex.

Comment: @Sosomqk See updates, and look to `Date and Time Styles`

Comment: @MartinSmith That what the OP want not me

Comment: probably only because they imagine it has some special semantics, what use do **you** think it has in your query given that the left hand side is a string in yyyy-mm-dd format?